# Set binding model at parent level

Tags: sapui5

I am working on getting my head around SAPUI5 and thinking about simplifying something but just cannot get it to work. I have got one simple form with few controls in XML view. Now I am assigning a model property to these controls. Model is getting created in a controller file as usual. My XML view is below

```xml
<form:SimpleForm>
  <Label text="Name" />
  <Input value="{search>/criteria/name}" />
  <Label text="Desc" />
  <Input value="{search>/criteria/desc}" />
</form:SimpleForm>
```

Now in above XML view, I have got input value attached to a model but every time I am adding new input, I have to write `search>/criteria/propName`. I just want to avoid that. What I want to achieve is something like below:

```xml
<form:SimpleForm setBindingHereAtParent="{search>/criteria}">
  <Label text="Name" />
  <Input value="{name}" />
  <Label text="Desc" />
  <Input value="{desc}" />
</form:SimpleForm>
```

In above example, as you can see I am setting some binding at parent level which is a form to simplify the model binding at controls level. I think it is possible but just couldn't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no option to set a "ParentBinding".

The only way I could think of to shorten the binding would be to make the `search` model the default model of the View, so you can omit the `search>` in the Bindings.

*IMHO I wouldn't use the "ParentBinding" even if it existed, as it is clearer, much more readable and easier to understand when each binding is written out.*